# Override Message Service inbound URL programatically

Tags: twilio

I have setup a trial Twilio account and have been investigating their 
**Programmable SMS** service. Within my account I have also setup a **Messaging Service**. When I send an SMS I am able to set the URL I wish Twilio to send all delivery events (e.g accepted, sent, delivered etc) to, using a field called `statusCallback`. However, I am wondering if it is also possible to set the URL for which I wish to receive any replies to the message being sent, as part of the send SMS call? I know I can change the incoming request URL within the **Messaging Services** area of my Twilio account dashboard, but I would like to be able to set this URL on a per SMS basis, as part of the send SMS API call.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I cannot see anything in the docs to suggest it is but I wanted to know definitively.

I hope the question makes sense but if any clarification is needed then please let me know.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: The incoming URL is at a Number level as far as I am aware not at a single SMS level

Comment: You could make an API call to the number entity using the SID and modify the URL on the fly but doing this for every message sent seems like too much. What is your use case? Usually people reply to the number they are texted from.

Comment: My use case is that I need to correlate outgoing SMS messages with incoming SMS replies based on a transaction ID. One approach is to store the SMS ID returned from Twilio Send API and use this ID to match outgoing SMS messages to incoming replies. However, this requires that my application maintain state. Ideally I'd like to be able to send this transaction ID to Twilio as part of my send SMS API call ( e.g via a custom HTTP header or query param in callback URL) and have that transaction ID be returned to me with any reply SMS messages. However, this appears  to not be possible.